# How to get the text from this element?

Tags: node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I use selenium webdriver with node js.
I cannot get the text from this site. I need the "In progress" text.
I don't want to use absolute xpath, because I want use the code in other tests.
Thank you. :)

```
<div class="issuePanelContainer" id="issue_actions_container" 
style="height: auto;">
  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%"> . 
</table>
<div class="issue-data-block">
  <div class="actionContainer">
<div class="action-details">
                <span class="aui-avatar aui-avatar-xsmall">
        <span class="aui-avatar-inner">
            <img alt="" src="https://jira.au.flitech.net/secure/useravatar?size=xsmall&amp;ownerId=jan.plzak%40flightcentre.co.uk&amp;avatarId=12582">
        </span>
      </span>
                            <a class="user-hover" rel="jan.plzak@flightcentre.co.uk" id="email_jan.plzak@flightcentre.co.uk" href="/secure/ViewProfile.jspa?name=jan.plzak%40flightcentre.co.uk">Jan Plzak</a>
              made transition
  - <span class="date" title="18/Jun/19 4:57 PM"><time class="livestamp" datetime="2019-06-18T16:57:08+1000">18/Jun/19 4:57 PM</time></span>
</div>
<div class="changehistory action-body">
  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
    <tbody><tr>
      <td width="60%">
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
          <tbody><tr>
            <td width="47%" align="right">
                                <span class=" jira-issue-status-lozenge aui-lozenge jira-issue-status-lozenge-blue-gray jira-issue-status-lozenge-new jira-issue-status-lozenge-max-width-medium" data-tooltip="<span class=&quot;jira-issue-status-tooltip-title&quot;>Open</span>" title="" original-title="">Open</span>                </td>
            <td align="center" nowrap="nowrap" width="6%">
              <img src="/images/icons/arrow_right_small.gif" align="absmiddle" border="0" height="16" width="16">
            </td>
            <td width="47%">
                                <span class=" jira-issue-status-lozenge aui-lozenge jira-issue-status-lozenge-yellow jira-issue-status-lozenge-indeterminate jira-issue-status-lozenge-max-width-medium" data-tooltip="<span class=&quot;jira-issue-status-tooltip-title&quot;>In Progress</span><br><span class=&quot;jira-issue-status-tooltip-desc&quot;>The development task is currently in progress</span>" title="" original-title="">In Progress</span></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody></table>
      </td>
      <td width="20%">
        13d 21h 18m 
      </td>
      <td width="20%" align="center">
          1
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody></table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my answer, which is working fine, and content free. :)
`driver.findElements(By.xpath('//div[@class="changehistory action-body"]/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/span'));`

Answer (score 0):

```
List<WebElement> list=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(@class,'status')]"));
    for(WebElement li:list)
    {
       if(li.getText().equals("In progress")
       {
         li.click();  // or assert or whatever
       }
   }
```